# Styling JavaScript made elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

I created a div element with JavaScript enclosed inside a function. Now how can I call the div element and give it some styling outside of that particular function. Need some suggestion.

```
function output(str, level) {
    var obj = document.getElementById("dvList1");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var node = document.createTextNode(str);
    div.style.marginLeft = (level * 20) + "px";
    div.appendChild(node);
    obj.appendChild(div);
    div.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: You cannot *call* an element, because an element is not a function. You can return `div` to whatever called `output` and process it further. Maybe if you could provide an example of what you exactly mean by *"give it some styling outside of that particular function"*, we could help you better.

Comment: You could give the element an ID or class, and use this to select the element - or you store it in a variable with a global scope.

Comment: div.style.display = "none"; like this ;)

Google for what css styling suits your needs and apply it like you did for display part.

Answer (score 1):

either return the div element from the function like this

```
function output(str, level) {
    var obj = document.getElementById("dvList1");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var node = document.createTextNode(str);
    div.style.marginLeft = (level * 20) + "px";
    div.appendChild(node);
    obj.appendChild(div);
    div.style.display = "none";
    return div;
}
```

and call it like

```
var div = output('test',11);
div.style.display = 'block';
```

or make the div element global like

```
var div = null;
function output(str, level) {
    var obj = document.getElementById("dvList1");
    div = document.createElement("div");
    var node = document.createTextNode(str);
    div.style.marginLeft = (level * 20) + "px";
    div.appendChild(node);
    obj.appendChild(div);
    div.style.display = "none";
}

output('test',11);
div.style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a className to the created `div` and style it in CSS.

See last line of function:

```
function output(str, level, cssClass) 
{
  var obj = document.getElementById("dvList1");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var node = document.createTextNode(str);
  div.style.marginLeft = (level * 20) + "px";
  div.appendChild(node);
  obj.appendChild(div);
  div.style.display = "none";

  if(cssClass)
    div.className = cssClass;

  return div;
}

var div = output('test', 3, 'red-border');
```

or mulitple class like:

```
var div = output('test', 3, 'red-border bold');
```

or adding after created:

```
var div = output('test', 3);
div.style.display = 'block';
div.className = 'red-border bold';
```

And the CSS:

```
.red-border { border: 1px solid red; }
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create the div element inside a function and style it in a different function.
but I will suggest assigning a class to div while creating and then use css to style the div element.